# Tableau find delta from previous value

Tags: tableau-api

Trying to build a line graph via a table that looks something like this

```
Date Value Delta New Value
1/1   1           
1/2   2      1    2
1/3   4      2    4 
1/4   2      -2   4
1/5   6      2    6
1/6   3      -3   6
```

Where if delta from previous value is positive, than add it to the 'new value' column, but if the delta is negative, then just carry over the last row's 'new value'. I'm essential trying to show a line graph of New value that is either only increasing, or constant for each step forward in time.

I've tried using lookup() and table calc with the logic below but I'm still getting negative slope when I plot the line graph and I'm not sure why.

```
IF ATTR(Value) > LOOKUP(ATTR(Value),-1)
THEN
ATTR(Value)-LOOKUP(ATTR(Value),-1)
+ LOOKUP(ATTR(Value),-1)
ELSE
LOOKUP(ATTR(Value),-1)
END
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why is New Value 2 for 1/2? Doesn't follow your rule literally.

Comment: Also, your ELSE clause looks suspicious. Are you sure you don't mean to lookup Attr(New Value)?